# How can I filter groups based on user_id in django-template-language

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

how can I filter the groups based on the user in Django-template-language with if else condition

```
 <tbody>
      {% for group in groups %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{group.name}}</td>                                       
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="add_group[]" id="group-{{group.id}}" value=" 
          {{group.id}}" 
                                   
           checked   
           ></td>
                                                                       
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}                                 
  </tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: It's best practice to have logic in the views or models instead of the templates. In your case, I would either filter in the view or add it to the user model. Please let me know if you need any help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an `User` group with [related object reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) or in [DTL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#variables) with a dot notation: `User.groups.all`.

For instance, if you want `checked` only in groups that a specific user is in:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('user/<int:id>/', views.user_detail, name='user-detail')
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def user_detail(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    context = {
        'user': user,
        'groups': groups
    }
    return render(request, 'user_group.html', context)
```

user_group.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Username: {{user.username}}</h1>

<h2>Groups</h2>
<tbody>
    {% for group in groups %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>                                   
        <td>
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                name="add_group[]" 
                id="group-{{group.id}}" 
                value="{{group.id}}" 
                {% if group in user.groups.all %} checked {% endif %}
            >
        </td>                                                        
     </tr>
   {% endfor %}                                 
</tbody>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sir I don't want new page to be open for Updating. I want the group should be come in the modal as you can se in uploaded image

Comment: Can I send the request(user.id) to the backend at the same time with the same archer tag that is triggering the modal